# Creating a remote branch from another remote branch which isn't master

Tags: git

Git is making me pull my hair out.  I know how to create a local branch that tracks a remote branch, but I want to create a remote branch which copies another remote branch, and then track.  Creating a remote branch is also easy, but it seems to always uses the codebase in master, not in an arbitrary branch.  What's the sequence of commands I need if I have these branches

```
origin/master
origin/somebranch
```

and I want

```
*somebranch2
origin/master
origin/somebranch
origin/somebranch2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git push origin origin/somebranch:refs/heads/somebranch2
git branch -b somebranch2 origin/somebranch2
```

The first command is the most direct way of making a copy of a branch on a remote. The second command is simply for setting up the local branch (and it will track the new remote branch `origin/somebranch2`).

Comment: I had just found this: http://github.com/guides/copy-a-remote-branch

Which worked for me.  I hope it's actually as simple as you say.